# How can I create a curved grid

Tags: grids

I would like to create a (preferably conformal, but not necessary) curved grid like this:

{Dead, unrecoverable image was here <sup><sub>(not in *Wayback Machine*, and original image domain is now a parked malware site)</sub></sup>}

trying to match the outline of a curve I have:
[image: curve]

Kind of like the lines on an athletics track, but a grid. How can I do this? Any program is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a candidate for Illustrator's [Blend Tool](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6443a.html#WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6442a):

> ### Create blends
>
> The Blend tool and Make Blend command let you create blends, which are
>   a series of intermediate objects and colors between two or more
>   selected objects.
>
> #### Create a blend with the Blend tool
>
> 1. Select the Blend tool.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
>    - To blend in sequential order with no rotation, click anywhere on each object, but avoid anchor points.
>    - To blend to a specific anchor point on an object, click the anchor
>        point with the Blend tool. When the pointer is over an anchor point,
>        the pointer changes from a white square to transparent with a black
>        dot in its center.
>    - To blend open paths, select an endpoint on each path.
> 3. When you are finished adding objects to the blend, click the Blend tool again.
>
> #### Create a blend with the Make Blend command
>
> 1. Select the objects you want to blend.
> 2. Choose Object > Blend > Make.

Here's what I made with the Blend Tool based off your image:

[image: Blend tool example]

This will easily create the concentric dividers. You can then manually add in the radial dividers by hand if you require them.

Comment: This looks like the result I want, but your steps are a bit too sparse for me to follow. For starters, it looks like you're blending two paths. How can I get the paths to follow the edge? I would really appreciate it if you would provide more detailed steps. Thanks.

Comment: @Curvy I took your image and created two paths (outer and inner) using the pen tool. I then applied the blend to those two paths. Where are you getting hung up?

Comment: It just looks really precise in your picture, like the path is following the exact edge of the image, where as mine just joins the points on the path with straight lines (maybe yours does too if zoomed in more). Should I just be adding  more points or is there something special I can do to get the path to snap to the edge? Thanks.

Comment: @Curvy if you come into the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) I can try and guide you along, comments aren't very good for discussion

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Photoshop's warp tool to manipulate on what you're trying to achieve:
[image: Photoshop wrap tool]

Comment: I tried warp before posting this question but unfortunately it's just too imprecise for what I need.